# Edit width of boxes on beamer titlepage

Tags: beamer

I want to shrink the white boxes around the `author` and `date` fields to the width of their content on the titlepage of the following `beamer` presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{The tediously long title of my presentation}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\setbeamercolor{author}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date}{bg=white}

\begin{document}
    {\usebackgroundtemplate{
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}
        }
        \begin{frame}
            \titlepage
        \end{frame}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can this be done? Manually adjusting the width would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack: redefine the title page an wrap the `beamercolorboxe`s in minipages of your desired widths:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{The tediously long title of my presentation}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\setbeamercolor{author}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date}{bg=white}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \end{minipage}

    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
    \vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
    {\usebackgroundtemplate{
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}
        }
        \begin{frame}
            \titlepage
        \end{frame}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. May I additionaly ask were within the files shipped with beamer the '\setbeamertemplate{title page}' code segment is from?

Comment: @Christoph90 It is from the default inner theme